# How to change css when scroll to element have class is '#wrap'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently, I asked a question relative similar with this question but not have an answer correct with my case because I don't have an example.

Today, I publish demo site to the server.

See at: [demo link](http://bit2.quavn.com/digital/)

Scroll to: **JOIN US**

I want to scroll to element `#wrap-container-join-us`, the element `.group-menu-top` will change background color menu with CSS.

Normally, I usually using this code:

```
var section = $("#wrap-container-join-us");
var sectionOffSet = section.offset().top;
var sectionHeight = section.height();

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($w.scrollTop() >= sectionOffSet && $w.scrollTop() <= (sectionOffSet + sectionHeight)) {
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#fff'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'#26ace2'});
  }else{
    $('.menu-burger').css({'color':'#26ace2'});
    $('.menu-bg').css({'background':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)'});
  }
});
```

But seem button **LOAD MORE** before element `#wrap-container-join-us` have an element hidden.

I think the height of section `#wrap-container-case-study` effect when I scroll to section `#wrap-container-join-us`. It's can't change the background of a menu.

But I don't know calculator to do that.

Comment: Yes, like this. But scroll to `celebrate great ideas` the javascript code working. It not working in `join us`.

Comment: Just remove `var $w_scroll =` and it will work for me.

Comment: Where have you defined $w ?

Comment: Sorry, the issues with code when writing the question. I was updated.

Comment: Hi, @PatrickMlr. It will fail because bottom button **Load More** have some another element. It will fail when the JS tried to calculator height of any elements.

Comment: If I implement your code, it works. If I scroll down to "Join Us", the background of the menu will change.

Comment: You paste the code to console? Yes, it working if paste code to console. But in my JS file, it not working.

Comment: @vanloc : Is it possible make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @vanloc Sir, I really try to understand your problem, but I don't get it. Could you please insert your code to a js-File in your site and tell us the location or create a working snippet? I can't find the implementation of your code in your site.

Comment: Please waiting. I will create a js fiddle snippet.

Comment: Please check jsfiddle at here: https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/4150/ . Seem it not work correctly. But you can see my source like that. The problem in button **Loads More** if have many elements hidden. It will fail.

Comment: @vanloc I've updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/4152/). Is the problem that if the height of the first-section is 100, but if you add more by "load more" and the height is now 300, but the second-section will be triggered while the view is still in the first-section? Is this what you're trying to say?

Comment: Yes. But the method to `Load More` in my site different with the method in JSFiddle.  You can see on my demo site at : http://bit2.quavn.com/digital/

Comment: @vanloc See my answer. Hope this will help. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I understood your problem, it's easy now.

**What did I change?**

I changed your Javascript. At the point where you show the next 3 list-items, you need to recalculate the offset of the second-section. After you did this, it works!

Just add `sectionOffSet = section.offset().top;` to it.

It's important that you first initialize the `var` above your "Load More", then do your "Load More"-Method with the recalculate, then your scroll function.

**Why is this order important?**

It's important because you need to initialize the `var` first so you can change it in your "Load More"-method.

When you open your site, the `var` will be initialized without the hided elements. So the hided elements won't be hided at the beginning. After your hide-mechanic loaded, you need to recalculate the offset, because the items are hided now.

That's it.

See this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var section = $("#section-2")
  var sectionOffSet = section.offset().top;
  var sectionHeight = section.height();
  
  size_li = $("#myList li").size();
  x = 3;
  $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    x = (x + 3 <= size_li) ? x + 3 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    sectionOffSet = section.offset().top;
  });
  sectionOffSet = section.offset().top;

  var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($w.scrollTop() >= sectionOffSet && $w.scrollTop() <= (sectionOffSet + sectionHeight)) {
      $('.menu-bg').css({
        'color': 'white'
      });
      $('#section-2').css({
        'background': 'black'
      });
    } else {
      $('.menu-bg').css({
        'color': 'red'
      });
      $('#section-2').css({
        'background': 'white'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#section-2,
#section-3 {
  height: 400px;
}

#section-1 {
  background: green;
}

#section-2 {
  background: white;
}

#section-3 {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section-1">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
</section>
<section id="section-2">
  <p class="menu-bg">Text should be change.</p>
</section>
<section id="section-3">
  <p>Some text</p>
</section>
```